# Calling a PHP Function From Another PHP File in WordPress

Tags: php, call

I am trying to work out how to call a function from an external PHP file.

So far I have this:

```
<?php

include("http://www.website.net/wp-content/plugins/monarch/monarch.php");

display_inline();

?>
```

The function **display_inline();** returns a string of HTML/CSS.

Just need to know if you think the syntax is correct?

Comment: What happens when you try it?  Did it work?

Comment: I first need to allow HTTP URLs on the server. It came back saying that I can't request a direct URL.

Comment: As you're accessing a file in a WordPress plugin, the chances are it has restrictions to make sure it can only be accessed by said WP install

Answer (score 1):

Yes that syntax is correct, however if you are making the request to that external file, it's going to return whatever the output of the executed `monarch.php` file was. If the file is local you'll have access to the functions. Unlike how HTML includes a CSS file, on the local system the path used by PHP should be relative to the **system** and not the **webroot**. You shouldn't need to be cautious about this so go ahead and try it.